# Awesome notification on tap not working on killed state

Tags: flutter, awesome-notifications

We are using firebase_messaging for notifications in our Flutter app and to customize notifications we are using awesome_notifications. The notification ontap flow is working fine in the background or foreground state. The problem is in a killed state, the callbacks are not working.

used `@pragma('vm:entry-point')` also to awesome_notifications background state listeners.
Also used `getInitialNotificationAction()` method in the hope of getting the event there but it's still not working.

The weird part is that the same setup is working on another Flutter project. Another observation is that when the firebase's background handler is called in a killed state which also has `@pragma('vm:entry-point')`, our main method gets called, and due to which `getInitialNotificationAction()` method also gets called when the app is killed.

The callback works fine in the killed state.